# Rails add_index algorithm: :concurrently still causes database lock up during migration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

In order to prevent database transaction errors during our migrations to the production site, we followed the advice outlined in https://github.com/LendingHome/zero_downtime_migrations (specifically outlined by https://robots.thoughtbot.com/how-to-create-postgres-indexes-concurrently-in), but during the creation of an index on a particularly large table, even the "concurrent" method of index creation locked the table and caused any ActiveRecord creates or updates on that table caused their respective transactions to fail with `PG::InFailedSqlTransaction` exceptions.

Here is what the migration looked like we're running Rails 4.2 (with ActiveRecord 4.2.7.1):

```
class AddTypeIndexToModel < ActiveRecord::Migration
  disable_ddl_transaction!

  def change
    add_index :model, :model_type_id, algorithm: :concurrently
  end
end
```

Comment: Did you use monkeypatch? How is indicated here https://github.com/barsoom/devbook/tree/master/deploy_without_downtime

Answer (score 6):

It turns out the issue was not related to that migration, but one prior that ran in the same batch that was adding a new column to the same table.

Because we added a column to the table, we hit this bug in Active Record https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/12330 which essentially causes all ActiveRecord operations in a transaction to fail due to a stale PreparedStatement until the server is restarted.

We will use the workarounds described in that issue from now on in our migrations.